# Why am I getting this error in the logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, documentroot

Ok so I just started a new ubuntu server 11.10 and i added the vhost and all seems ok ...I also restarted apache but when i visit the browser i get a [blank page](http://23.21.197.126/)

the server ip is http://23.21.197.126/ but when i tail the log

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Wed Feb 01 02:19:20 2012] [error] [client 208.104.53.51] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Wed Feb 01 02:19:24 2012] [error] [client 208.104.53.51] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
```

but my only file in sites-enabled is this

```
<VirtualHost 23.21.197.126:80>
         ServerAdmin something@gmail.com
         ServerName logicxl.com
         # ServerAlias
         DocumentRoot /srv/crm/current/public
         ErrorLog /srv/crm/logs/error.log

           <Directory "/srv/crm/current/public">
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

is there something i am missing .....the document root should be `/srv/crm/current/public` and not `/etc/apache2/htdocs` as the error suggests

Any ideas on how to fix this

UPDATE

```
sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
23.21.197.126:80       is a NameVirtualHost
     default server logicxl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/crm:1)
     port 80 namevhost logicxl.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/crm:1)
Syntax OK
```

UPDATE

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin something@gmail.com
    ServerName logicxl.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/crm/current/public
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/crm/current/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: updated my question with an answer

Comment: Are new errors occurring when you attempt to load the site?

Comment: fixed by changing the vhost....but i have no idea how...i am pasting my new vhost and if you can let me know what might have fixed the earlier issue

Comment: Huh.  Is `/srv/crm/current/public` a symlink?

Comment: the current folder is a symlink

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2357/discussion-between-matt-and-shane-madden)

Comment: Then your adding of the `FollowSymLinks` option will have fixed it.  I guess the symlink is pointing to that `/etc` location?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like apache is not finding your sites-enabled directory.
Look in your apache2.conf file (etc/apache2/apache2.conf) for a line like this:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

Change it to an absolute path like this:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed but here is the last few lines of the apache2.conf...i will update my question with them

Comment: fixed it with another vhost but can you look at the other vhost and tell me the difference

Comment: did you restart after changing the line or after changing the vhost lines?

Comment: i restarted after both and your change didnt do anything but the vhost change did

Comment: strange since the only real difference in the vhost config is the  <Directory /> line and that one should not even be there since <Directory> usually only takes absolute paths

Comment: the current folder is a symlink if that matters

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to:

```
<VirtualHost 23.21.197.126:80>
```

Any request to `http://localhost` could have missed the initial vhost definition.

You then then changed it (correctly) to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Unless you have a specific reason you should always use `*:80` as this defines what address to **listen** on. `ServerName` defines what name to respond to . For example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: <Virtualhost IP:Port> is actually the better method. There will be a time when you want the server to be able to reference itself only. Enabling that feature later when you have a ton of services defined already will be a pain in the behind, as the two methods are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add the new site to apache:

```
$ sudo a2ensite (your project name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, in my case it was simply due to... sites-available/default not being linked to sites-enabled/default.

In apache2.conf I have:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

And my sites-enabled/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
  <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is a `VirtualHost` directive for the interface IP you are making the query to. This error happens, as also detailed above, when apache can find no server configuration to answer your query - but it is listening to it in ports.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error after a system upgrade. I modified `UserDir` `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`. Original:

```
Userdir public_html
```

new:

```
Userdir /home/*/public_html
```

works great now :)